# Subcaption in nonfloat environment

Tags: captions, subcaption

I have an `alltt` environment for which I'd like to add captions and sometimes subcaption, in the form: `Example 1a: some description`. However, I am only able to achieve : `a: some description`. I realize it would be easier with a float but, I need the environment to be able to span from one page to another. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=example] {example}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{example}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
\blindtext
\end{alltt}
\captionof{subexample}{Some description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry! Somehow when I copied the code over a bracket was lost - it should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\DeclareCaptionSubType{example}` macro does only provide the `subexample` type of the relevant `example` type, but not its name, this must be done separately with `\captionsetup[subtype]{name=Example}` (or choose any other name than `Example`)

If the counter of `subexample` should be reset with each `example` step, use `\DeclareCaptionSetupType*{example}` instead.

The `a` in `a: some description` comes from `\thesubexample` which is defined as `\@nameuse{alph{subexample}}`, which is effectively the same as `\alph{subexample}` here.

Perhaps `\renewcommand{\thesubexample}{\Alph{subexample}}` would be better here, but that is matter of taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=example]{example}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{example}
\captionsetup[subexample]{name=Example}

\renewcommand{\thesubexample}{\theexample\alph{subexample}}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\stepcounter{example}% Faking an already existing usage of `example` 
\begin{alltt}
\blindtext
\end{alltt}
\captionof{subexample}{Some description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I must admit that I do not really understand how the parent example and the subexample comes into action in the really O.P. document

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen: Happy TeXing then ;-)